# how many data in Arduino progmem?

Tags: arduino, memory

How much data can I save using `PROGMEM`, on the Arduino platform (Atmega328)?

For example:

```
prog_char path[] PROGMEM = {'M',103,95,'U',0,0,'M',103,95,'M',103,95,'M',103,95,'M',103,95,'M',
103,95,'M',103,95,'M',103,95,'M',101,94,'M',100,93,'M',99,92,'M',98,91,'M',98,90,'M',97,89,'M',
96,87,'M',95,85,'M',95,85,'M',94,85,'M',94,84,'M',93,82,'M',92,82,'M',92,82,'M',90,79,'M',89,78,
'M',89,78,'M',88,77,'M',88,75,'M',87,75,'M'}
```

(Numbers go up to 180.)

Where can i find this information?

Comment: The stack is in program memory?

Comment: @tyblu, AngryEE is right to question, stack is in SRAM, `PROGMEM` macro places stuff in program memory (flash)

Comment: Perhaps I should familiarize myself with Arduinos before commenting in the future, @JonL ;) ... comment deleted.

Comment: @tyblu, Just an FYI, Not sure if you're into Atmel's offerings, but the `PROGMEM` macro and types are defined in the avr-gcc library `pgmspace.h` - very useful if you're trying to squeeze as much as you can out of your AVR :) (so not just an Arduino specific thing)

Answer (score 4):

To see how much memory is available on your arduino, check the GUI after it uploaded the code: "Binary sketch size x bytes (of y byte maximum)". \$ y-x \$ would be the amount available to place data in.

Or check the tech specs of your Arduino for the value of Flash Memory. All Arduinos with a 328 offer 32kByte of flash, 2k of which is taken by the bootloader, your sketch may take 4k or so, to be on the safe side I would not store more than 20kByte of data.

Comment: ok and so i can compute how many char i can put it with: __(y-x)/2__ considering a prog_char type 2 bytes long. is it right?

Comment: prog_char is 1 byte long. You can check the size of a type with the sizeof function, see http://coverclock.blogspot.com/2012/02/arduino-data-types.html